# How to get depth of tree of arrays given total num items and max array size?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, tree

Given this `divide` algorithm and sample data:

```js
const data = [
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0
]

function divide(data, size) {
  const result = []

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += size) {
    const chunk = data.slice(i, i + size);
    result.push(chunk)
  }

  if (result.length > size) {
    return divide(result, size)
  }

  return result;
}

const result = divide(data, 5);
console.log(result)
```

How do you calculate the number of levels in the resulting tree? In this case of block size `5`, I think there are 3 are 4 levels about, but what is the equation to use so you don't have to compute the actual tree? Basically `getDepth(numItems, blockSize)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every recursive call reduces the input size by a factor of blocksize.

Starting with your example of 100 items.  This is grouped into 20, these 20 are grouped into 4 and the algorithm ends.

The expression that capture this is log with a base of blocksize.

```
f(n,m) = ceil(log_base_m(n))
```

Answer (score 3):

The depth of the example tree is

ceil(log<sub>5</sub>(99))

In general:

ceil(log<sub>chunksize</sub>(datasize-1))